# how does xelement handle special(xml) characters?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

If I declare a new Xelement and input string as for example **`address.line1 = "<address>"`** how will the following statement handle special characters such as `<, >,/` in the following line of code?

```
XElement a = new XElement("address",
                     new XElement("addressline1", address.Addressline1),
                                 );
```

Will this throw error or will this encode the special characters that the user inputs?

Comment: Very (very) easy to find out.

Comment: @HenkHolterman My class is too much big and complex to test this moment :(

Comment: @FloodGravemind Then get a copy of LinqPad, or write a quick Console App, or a Unit Test :)

Comment: @DaveShaw Thanks Dave didnt know about this tool. +1

Comment: You didn't know about console applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Xelement encodes Characters
Test Code

```
void Main()
{
string m = "<address/>";
XElement a = new XElement("address",
                         new XElement("addressline1",m)
                                      );
Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Result

```
<address>
       <addressline1>&lt;address/&gt;</addressline1>
       </address>
```

Comment: If you ran even a tiny application you'd find that it will convert `<`, `>`, and `&` to `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` respectively. Besides, one would assume if [`string` is a valid content for an XElement object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx) that it would have any conversions applied to ensure it is appropriate. As an aside, this has nothing to do with the  *encoding* of your XML. Do not conflate standard XML entities and encoding.

Comment: @user7116 I am trying to use LinqPad as  DaveShaw suggested.